# Why does my object created with "new" not exist out of scope?

Tags: c++

Hi and sorry for this propably incredibly stupid question - complete C++ beginner here..
I understood that creating objects with the "new" operator creates them on the heap and that they therefor should be global, right? 
I tried this with this code, but end up getting an error, that I read as "out of scope" - what am I not seeing here, guys?

```
int main()
{   
    bool mainLoop = true; 
    do 
    {
        string userInput1, userInput2;
        cout << endl << "Please enter a new recipe, or press X to quit: " << endl << endl;
        cin >> userInput1; 
        if (userInput1 != "x") 
        {
            cout << endl << "Please enter the recipes description: " << endl << endl;
            cin >> userInput2;
            Recipe *gulasch1 = new Recipe (userInput1, userInput2);
            gulasch1->speak(); // this is just to try out if this outputs anything, and it does
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "Thanks and goodbye!" << endl; 
            mainLoop = false;
        } 
    } while (mainLoop == true);

    gulasch1->speak(); // why does this throw an error? ('gulasch1': undeclared identifier)

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if this is duplicate (I imagine it has to be, but I couldn't find anything that answered my question. 
Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: Distinguish pointer and its pointee.

Comment: Names have scope, objects have lifetime. Objects don't have names, variables do.

Answer (score 3):

You are conflating two *different* objects. `gulasch1` is a pointer. It *points* at a dynamically allocated object, yes. But `gulasch1` itself is a separate object that has block scope.

If you want it available in the scope of `main` after the loop, define it before the loop, and turn the initialization inside the loop into assignment.

Comment: when I initialize my object before and assign a nullptr to it, I get "Recipe gulasch1 = nullptr;"

Comment: @ThiloG - `Recipe *gulasch1 = nullptr;`, *not* `Recipe gulasch1 = nullptr;`. Note the asterisk. You want a pointer.

Comment: Alright, thanks - but how do I assign inside the scope then? when trying `gulasch1 = *pGulasch1; ` i get "cannot convert from 'Recipe' to 'Recipe *'"

Comment: Ok, I think I got it working.. I guess it was `gulasch1 = pGulasch1;` to assign the in-scope pointer to the outta-scope pointer and then `gulasch1->speak();`when I want to call the method... sorry, this really shouldn't be that hard, but pointers still confuse me immensely...

Comment: @ThiloG - They are indeed an hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `gulasch1` is only in the scope of the `if` statement so it can't be used outside. What you have here is a compilation issue - nothing to do with heap vs stack. Yes the actual `Recipe` is on the heap and (if it compiled) would still be there after the `while` loop, but you have no variable pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

The object `Recipe` that you point to exists outside of the scope you created it in because you made that object on the free store (heap) using `new`.

But the pointer `Recipe*` pointing to it (`gulasch1`) only exists in the scope you created it in, because you made it an automatic (stack) variable.